# Redirecting both http and https requests to new host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

In Apache 2.4.6, I would like to redirect requests from `http://A.org/foo` and `https://A.org/foo` to `https://B.org/foo`.

I am using the following directives:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
     ServerName B.org
     ServerAlias A.org
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^B.org$
     RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://B.org/$1 [R=permanent,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
     ServerName B.org
     ServerAlias A.org
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443(s)
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^B.org$
     RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://B.org/$1 [R=permanent,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit `http://A.org/foo`, this redirects to `https://B.org/foo` (correct).

When I visit `https://A.org/foo`, this loads `https://B.org/foo` but does not rewrite the URL. So I get an SSL certificate domain mismatch error from the web browser.

Is there something wrong with the second `VirtualHost` directive which would keep the URL from being rewritten?

Comment: Comment out `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443(s)` line and retest after clearing browser cache.

Comment: I get the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL certificate has to be validated before the redirect can be issued, so you will need to use a certificate that is valid for 'A.org' within the VirtualHost that is issuing the redirect from `https://A.org/`, and separate it from the VirtualHost serving `https://B.org/`.

The line checking server port is not necessary because the VirtualHost only serves that port anyway. Just remove it.

Here's an outline with the rules also slightly tweaked for aesthetics which you may or may not prefer!

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
     ServerName B.org
     ServerAlias A.org
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=B.org
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://B.org$1 [R=permanent,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
     ServerName A.org
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://B.org$1 [R=permanent,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
     ServerName B.org
</VirtualHost>
```