# Why Apache configuration works when I use root directory

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

I have a `VirtualHost` that I am using to serve requests to files in `/var/www/project/src`.

I also have a Perl script (CGI binary) that is in `/var/www/project/src/cgi-bin/index.pl`.

Here's the part of the directive relevant to my question:

```
<VirtualHost example.com:443>
    ...
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/project/src"
    <Directory "/var/www/project/src">
        Require all granted
        Options +MultiViews +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .pl
        DirectoryIndex /cgi-bin/index.pl
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The server starts, but access to the host fails as I get a 403 error.

The Apache logs indicate that the web server cannot find `{document-root}/cgi-bin/index.pl`:

```
[Thu Nov 09 11:37:03.578316 2017] [autoindex:error] 
  [pid 122783] [client example-client.com:57203] AH01276: 
  Cannot serve directory /var/www/project/src/: No matching
  DirectoryIndex (/cgi-bin/index.pl) found, and server-
  generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

This directory and `index.pl` file are in the right location, are owned by the `apache` user, and have permissions which allow others to read the contents of directories and execute the `index.pl` CGI-bin.

Moreover, if I change paths in `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` variables, the following configuration works:

```
<VirtualHost example.com:443>
    ...
    DocumentRoot "/"
    <Directory "/">
        Require all granted
        Options +MultiViews +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .pl
        DirectoryIndex /var/www/project/src/cgi-bin/index.pl
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache starts up, and my access to the host in turn loads `/cgi-bin/index.pl`, which is rendered correctly.

Question: What would cause the first set of directives to fail, where the second set works?

More specifically: What is preventing the first set of directives from finding `/cgi-bin/index.pl` in the specified document root, while the second set correctly finds the fully-qualified path `/var/www/project/src/cgi-bin/index.pl`?

Note: The items in `...` do not seem relevant to the issue — whether I remove them, alter them, or leave them, the error and log messages are the same in any case — so I am leaving them out for brevity.

Comment: This looks like something better suited to [sf]

Comment: @pvg not sure of that ;-)

Comment: @Alex Reynolds i dont think that you do have a directory on your server with this path "/cgi-bin/index.pl". Is your problem maybe about understanding absolute vs relative paths?

Comment: @Harry that's why there's a [help/on-topic], to enlighten then unsure.

Comment: @Harry No, I don't believe that is the issue. This is why I set the `Directory` and `DocumentRoot` parameters. See the following for discussion: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: I have asked Apache configuration questions on SO many times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600632/access-control-expose-headers-setting-ignored https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816301/redirecting-both-http-and-https-requests-to-new-host https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356811/how-to-send-compressed-deflated-svg-via-apache2 etc. I respectfully ask that you please take off-topic concerns to chat.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing permissions for /var/www, /var/www/project, /var/www/project/src and/or /var/www/project/src/cgi-bin

Update: Also, don't forget to restart Apache server after making changes.

Comment: Permissions for parent and children directories are read and executable for others, and read/write/executable for the apache user.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is <strike>your excessive zeal</strike> an excess in your zeal... in the first example, `DirectoryIndex /cgi-bin/index.pl` points towards your ROOT directory, then searching for a folder caller `cgi-bin`. This also happens in the second example, but since you give the full path, Apache finds it. Try removing the `/` before `cgi-bin` and the issue should fix itself.

Comment: I don't think Apache's documentation on DirectoryIndex agrees with you, as it indicates that index files are searched from the root directory. Your advice did not have any effect, in any case.